# Template specialization crash

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, c++14

Fellow SOers,

Im using (trying to use) a combination of template specialization, integer sequences and tuples to use variadic templates to retrieve parameters from an 
API, depending on the method signature. My program crashes when executing the function that does just this. Can anybody give me a hint as to why this could happen? Im trying to bind a function of the signature `int(*)(std::string)`.
Here is where the function is used/where the lambda used for binding is created:

```
template<typename T_Return, typename ... T_Params>
void bindFunction(T_Return(*function_item)(T_Params ...))
{
    std::function<T_Return(T_Params ...)> proxy_func(function_item);
    duk_function_t func = [proxy_func] (duk_context* ctx) mutable ->   duk_ret_t {
        const int n_Args = sizeof...(T_Params);
        if(duk_get_top(ctx)==n_Args)
        {
            if(std::is_same<T_Return, void>::value)
            {
                detail::duk_get_args<T_Return, T_Params ...>(ctx, proxy_func);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                detail::duk_return(ctx, detail::duk_get_args(ctx, proxy_func)); //Program crashes in this line
                return 1;
            }
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    m_Function = func;
}
```

The program crashes at that specific point in code.

And lastly, here is how i retrieve data from the API via template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
inline T duk_get_arg(duk_context* ctx, int i);

template<>
inline std::string duk_get_arg<std::string>(duk_context* ctx, int i)
{
    char* ret_str;
    strcpy(ret_str, duk_require_string(ctx, i));
    std::string ret(ret_str);
    return ret;
}

template<>
inline int duk_get_arg<int>(duk_context* ctx, int i)
{
    int ret = duk_require_int(ctx, i);
    return ret;
}

template<>
inline unsigned int duk_get_arg<unsigned int>(duk_context* ctx, int i)
{
    unsigned int ret = duk_require_int(ctx, i);
    return ret;
}

template<>
inline float duk_get_arg<float>(duk_context* ctx, int i)
{
    float ret = (float)duk_require_number(ctx, i);
    return ret;
}

template<>
inline double duk_get_arg<double>(duk_context* ctx, int i)
{
    double ret = duk_require_number(ctx, i);
    return ret;
}

template<typename T_Return, typename ... T_Params, size_t ... T_Is>
inline T_Return duk_get_args_impl(duk_context* ctx, std::function<T_Return(T_Params ...)>& function_item, std::index_sequence<T_Is ...>)
{
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<T_Params ...>;
    T_Return ret;
    ret = function_item(duk_get_arg<std::tuple_element_t<T_Is, tuple_type>>(ctx, T_Is) ...);
    return ret;
}
template<typename T_Return, typename ... T_Params>
inline T_Return duk_get_args(duk_context* context, std::function<T_Return(T_Params ...)>& function_item)
{
    T_Return ret;
    ret = duk_get_args_impl<T_Return, T_Params ...>(context, function_item, std::index_sequence_for<T_Params ...>());
    return ret;
}
```

Is there anything i am missing/doing fundamentally wrong? Except for using lambdas this way? I really do hope for an answer, since i cant make out what is causing the error! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `char* ret_str; strcpy(ret_str, duk_require_string(ctx, i));` I perceive the problem

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the thing, is my answer cant be minimal AND complete. I think this is as minimal as it can get, and as i said, the binding works fine, and i just checked if the values contained within the lambda the moment it is executed are fine aswell. they are. So the problem solely lies within my implementation of `duk_get_args`. @PiotrSkotnicki what do you mean, am i doing something wrong here? i am copying a const `char*` to a `char*`.

Comment: @calcyss `ret_str` is uninitialized, you are invoking UB trying to copy something to a memory space pointed by an uninitizlied pointer

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki really? i was under the impression that strcpy() also allocates memory. Is that not the case?

Comment: @calcyss *"strcpy() also allocates memory"* where did you learn this from ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki As i said, i was _under the impression_ that it does that. Guess i should read the documentation next time :D

Comment: i'll answer my own question then. Thanks very much.

Comment: Classic `char*` problem.

Comment: @calcyss Your question can definitely be minimal and complete. Just keep deleting things until you can produce something that's self-sufficient that still reproduces the error. Chances are, just by doing that, you'll find the problem yourself. As-is, this is just a blob of code, which many functions undefined, that Piotr happened to notice a problem in. Not a good way to actually get help.

Comment: thanks. ill try to trim this question a bit and will keep what you said in mind :)

Comment: are the downvotes only because my question was badly structured, or because the answer was so obvious it made the question obsolete? :D

Comment: @calcyss this problem could be made minimal.  For each line, if you remove it, does the bug still happen?  `std::cout << "wrong number of arguments! retreating!" << std::endl;` I bet deleting that line would still make the code crash, and that took me 5 seconds to find.  Either you aren't able to delete lines of code, or you didn't try?  After you have finished that process, you can then work on the logic -- can you reproduce the problem skipping entire layers of your logic?  Work out where the crash happens, reproduce just that line of code and reproduce the crash?  Yes, this takes work.

Comment: @Yakk, oh you meant minimal as in removing fundamentally unnecessary code parts like debug couts. ok then, sorry i didn't read the guidelines thoroughly.

Comment: @calcyss no, that was just an example of something that was clearly not minimal.  Piles of the rest of your code are also not required to reproduce the crash.  The end result of my above process is `char* ret_str; strcpy(ret_str, "hello");` crashing, and you posting "why is this `strcpy` crashing?"  Or maybe you'd figure it out yourself when you got to that point: finding the point where your code crashed, reproduce a sketch of the state and testing that to see if you can reproduce it is one of the steps you should go through to generate a MCVE.

Comment: @Yakk. absolutely. i will keep that in mind in the future, but as to narrowing that down, i expected the problem to be with how i used template specialization, not with the specialized functions at all. I'll make sure to do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was just my misunderstanding/me being too lazy to look up the documentation of `strcpy()`. It does not allocate memory for the target string, i had to do that. Changing the `get_arg<std::string>` method a bit did the trick,  with

```
template<>
inline std::string duk_get_arg<std::string>(duk_context* ctx, int i)
{
    std::string ret(duk_require_string(ctx, i));
    return ret;
}
```

i now get the following output:

```
>> var x = cnum("3");
"3"
>> print(x);
6
>>
```

Thanks again for the quick (and obvious) answers! Made me learn a lesson too :P